# Display Chitika ads without javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ads

Okay, I am developing a web application using MVC 4 and I want to display Ads from Chitika. I don't want these ad's to be blocked by the client side.  I was wondering if it is possible to have the javascript for the chitika ads on a static html page.

```
<div class="ads">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ch_client = "";
    ch_width = 728;
    ch_height = 90;
    ch_type = "";
    ch_sid = "";
    ch_color_site_link = "0000CC";
    ch_color_title = "0000CC";
    ch_color_border = "F4F1E6";
    ch_color_text = "000000";
    ch_color_bg = "F4F1E6";
</script>
<script src="http://scripts.chitika.net/eminimalls/amm.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>
```

And then call the page like so:

```
 var Request =    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("/adsstatic.html");
        var adResult = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

        Stream receiveStream = adResult.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        return readStream.ToString();
```

and then display the returned html on the view? Is this totally stupid?

Thanks

Comment: ad companies typically want thier script code running on the actual client to prevent cheating.

Comment: You're just fetching the posted html/script source, and embedding it into the page server-side? And then sending the resulting document to the client? That's no different from just including the markup/script inline in your document in the first place. The client gets sent the exactly same document either way.